# how to get new patch list of HP-UX

Tags: hp-ux, system-administration

I need get the patch list of `HP-UX 11.31` for develop a automatic tools to check is this Server needs  to be update. All servers was in secure local domain, so I want use `swlist -l patch` command to get current server's patch list, like

```
Active          Patch
Patch           Description
----------      -----------------------------------------
PHCO_36038      esmd(1M) cumulative patch
PHCO_36075      documentation change needed for stat(5)
PHCO_36254      uptime(1) cumulative patch
PHCO_36309      diskinfo(1M) patch
PHCO_36392      Japanese documentation change needed for stat(5)
PHCO_36447      aries(5) man page patch
```

and compare it with new patch list ,so I can get what patch was not applied 。

My question is , where can I get patch list like `PHCO_XXXXX PHKL_XXXXX PHNE_XXXXX PHSS_XXXXX`?

Comment: like AIX , I can get fixpack name from offical website , like 5300-12-09-1341 , but i cannot found it with hpe.com

Answer (score 1):

You need a software support contract with HPE, and associate that contract with your "passport" in this site:

https://h20565.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc

After that, under Product Support->Download options->patch management, you have access to latest patches for your systems.

You can even upload your current list of patches and get a patch assessment.